# Get Appenders from Log4Net LogManager

Tags: c#, .net, logging, config, log4net

I'm trying to get name of the file with log by log4net, but I can't get my Appenders. This is my config:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="name.log"/>
      <appendToFile value="false"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="0"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <foreColor value="Red, HighIntensity"/>
      </mapping>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

This is the code for getting count of appenders:

```
((Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).GetAppenders().Length.ToString();
```

But it gives me 0.
Logging works perfectly, so config works for logging. Do you have any ideas how to get the appenders or file name `"name.log"` from config without appenders? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you're fetching the appenders before your call to Configure?

Using the config you provided:

```
int count;
count = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().Length; // 0
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
count = LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().Length; // 2
```